# Sort highest to lowest without built in

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I write a sort function that sorts from highest to lowest without built in function?

For example:

```
A=[2,4,6]
sorthightolow(A)
A=[6,4,2]
```

Comment: why without built in ??

Comment: If your boss asks you not use use built ins you should quit the job. If the teacher/prof asks you not to use built ins you should do it on your own - or at least provide some code and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: post it to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com - it's the right place for "codegolf" :D

Comment: Search for sorting technics like bubble sort.

Comment: In general, implement a sorting algorithm. There are many choices, including bubble sort as shown above. You can probably come up with a sorting algorithm by yourself (which may not be the most efficient, however) - think about how you would sort the numbers by hand and implement that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dunno why one would do it without built-in functions, but here's a working bubble sort example. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort#Python

```
def bubble_sort(seq):
    """Inefficiently sort the mutable sequence (list) in place.
       seq MUST BE A MUTABLE SEQUENCE.

       As with list.sort() and random.shuffle this does NOT return 
    """
    changed = True
    while changed:
        changed = False
        for i in xrange(len(seq) - 1):
            if seq[i] > seq[i+1]:
                seq[i], seq[i+1] = seq[i+1], seq[i]
                changed = True
    return seq

if __name__ == "__main__":
   """Sample usage and simple test suite"""

   from random import shuffle

   testset = range(100)
   testcase = testset[:] # make a copy
   shuffle(testcase)
   assert testcase != testset  # we've shuffled it
   bubble_sort(testcase)
   assert testcase == testset  # we've unshuffled it back into a copy
```